# How to edit every node of a content type on cron run?

Tags: 7, cron

On cron runs, I want to edit every node of a certain content type. I think this is implemented through `hook_cron()` but I can't find any documentation about this hook. How can I edit every node of a certain content type on cron runs?

I need this because I update content on nodes based on another website. I want the content to be updated regularly. I need something similar to feeds but the data source is just HTML not xml.

Comment: Editing all nodes during a cron run is a recipe for disaster, and I would strongly advice you against it. If you are trying to edit all nodes on Drupal only once, then you would be far better off with [`hook_update()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_update/7)

Comment: Why exactly do you need to edit every nodes of a content type, and what do you need to edit?

Comment: I updated the quesiton

Comment: Possibly dupe of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45539/how-can-i-quickly-re-save-all-the-nodes-on-my-site-to-trigger-a-rule-that-activ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to implement various hooks.

[hook_cron](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7): It will get called on every cron run. Here you could load every node in the system using [node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load/7), edit whatever properties of the node you need to edit, and then save each edited node using [node_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_save/7).

However, note that both loading and saving a node **is** an expensive process, and if you have a site with many nodes, your site would become very slow, unstable, or even unusable on every cron run (which can sometimes happen as often as every 15-30 minutes). In other words, I would be very cautious with whatever you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [the documentation for hook_cron](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7).

Can you be a little more specific about what you want to do? My first thought is to recommend [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations), but that's more for one-time updates rather than every-cron-run updates.