# How can I quickly re-save all users on my site?

Tags: users, views, batch-operations

Very similar to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45539/how-can-i-quickly-re-save-all-the-nodes-on-my-site-to-trigger-a-rule-that-activ) except I need to save users, not nodes.

Use case: I added a field (single boolean) to a feature so that the field is added to user profiles.  I then pushed the feature to my staging server.  However, existing user accounts do not have the default field value for this field assigned.  Re-saving each account fixes the problem, but there are 1000 users.

How can I quickly re-save all users on my site?

Comment: Users are entities too, you can use exactly the same logic from the other question (VBO with PHP, or a manual update) and just replace `node_save()` with `user_save()`

Comment: @Clive @rooby Thanks for the tips here.  I just tried `user_save($entity)`; this causes the user to be saved (I confirmed by adding a rule that shows a message on the site).  However, no value is assigned to the new field, even if I run the save action multiple times.  If I do it manually, though, from the People page, the default value is set.

Comment: How about forcing it through...`$items = field_get_items('user', $entity, 'field_name'); if (empty($items)) { $entity->field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 1; } user_save($entity);` That should do the trick

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the "Execute arbitrary PHP script" bulk operation in VBO and when you run it enter:

```
user_save($entity);
```

You could also run this PHP (you can do so by enabling the devel module and going to devel/php on your site):

```php
set_time_limit(0);
$uids = db_query('SELECT uid FROM {users} WHERE uid != 0')->fetchCol();
$users = user_load_multiple($uids);
foreach ($users as $user) {
  user_save($user);
}
```

If you don't have many users you shouldn't need the time limit line.

Also, Clive mentions that field_attach_update is faster. To use that replace the user_save line with field_attach_update('user', $user)

Comment: What is the VBO save action for users?  I looked for it but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @Patrick is there not a generic save action for entities? (I haven't checked I just assumed there would be)

Comment: @Clive No, there is *Modify entity values* but nothing with the word "save" in it...

Comment: My mistake, there is a "Save content" one for nodes but no equivalent user one. I have removed that part of my answer.

Comment: In that case I'd go with the manual query; but I'd alter it slightly to avoid changing the user properties (i.e. use `field_attach_update()` instead of `user_save()`)

Comment: Thanks, I put a note about field_attach_update().
I also added an even nicer solution using VBO execute PHP code (thanks Bojan)

Comment: The first option seems a lot easier...is the `$user` object definitely available in the arbitrary PHP execution?

Comment: Oops, that was a typo, thanks for picking that up.

Comment: The PHP code via Devel worked great. I had to add 'WHERE uid > 0' to avoid an integrity constraint error in the logs.

Answer (score 5):

rooby's answer is probably the easiest/quickest method but just to offer a code solution that can be used with VBO...

You can define your own action to save the user like this:

```
function MYMODULE_rules_action_info() {
  return array(
   'MYMODULE_update_user_account' => array(
     'label' => t('Save a user account'),
     'parameter' => array(
       'account' => array(
         'type' => 'user',
         'label' => t('User'),
       ),
     ),
     'group' => t('MODULENAME'),
   ),
 );
}

function MYMODULE_update_user_account($account) {
  user_save($account);
}
```

Once you've clerared the caches you should see your new action appear under VBO/rules and anywhere else actions are used.

Edit: It seems this might re-inventing the wheel somewhat if VBO will already let you do it natively, but it's a nice simple example of a rules action so I'll leave it here in case anyone needs it. Plus it removes the need for `eval()` to be used which is never a bad thing.

Comment: Seeing as this is now the leading answer, if anyone actually does end up doing it this way, please submit it back as a patch. The rightful module is the user module because the node module provides the save content action, however there might be more chance of it being committed to the views_bulk_operations module. - Maybe a drupal 8 user module patch that might have a chance at back port to 7.